# how to read a list of current running process in linux using C++

Tags: c++

i need to read the list of current running process into a C++ program. 
I know that one way to do is to use ps command and other is to read /proc file system but i want to know how one can get names of processes by reading /proc file system.
also is there any other way to read the list.

Answer (score 2):

There is no other way to read the list, /proc exists for this purpose.  The simplest way to find out exactly how to do this job would be to read the source for [procps](http://procps.sourceforge.net/), which may include a library to do most of the work for you.

Answer (score 2):

you might want to try out [libstatgrab](http://www.i-scream.org/libstatgrab/docs/sg_get_process_stats.3.html), it should be able to give you unified access to that information on many different operating systems. It will still open /proc on GNU/Linux, but you won't know.

Answer (score 0):

You can read all information from `/proc/<process pid>/`. I guess the file `cmdline` and the link `exe` in each of these directories will be relevant for you.