# Launcher for Java

Tags: java, c++

I have a jar file for which I created a custom c++ launcher script. I can't figure how to permit only one instance of the program to run. Is there a way to detect already running jvm?

Here's the launcher code-

```
#include <string>
#include <direct.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int arg_count, char* arg_list[]) {

    string exeName(arg_list[0]);
    string rootDir = exeName.substr(0, exeName.find_last_of("\\"));
    string jarFile = ".\\dist\\PlayIt.jar";
    string cmd;
    string javaCmdFile = ".\\jre\\bin\\javaw.exe";

    _chdir(rootDir.c_str());

    if (arg_count == 1) {
        cmd = "start " + javaCmdFile + " -jar " + jarFile + " visible";
    }
    else if (arg_count > 1) {
        cmd = "start " + javaCmdFile + " -jar " + jarFile + " invisible";
        for (int i = 1; i < arg_count; i++) {
            cmd += " \"" + string(arg_list[i]) + "\"";
        }
    }
    system(cmd.c_str());
}
```

Comment: Do you want to run only one instance of JVM or only one instance of `PlayIt.jar`?

Comment: Only one instance of PlayIt.jar

Comment: It's probably easier to ensure that only one copy of your launcher is running using an interprocess mutex

Comment: You can [get list of running processes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2206912/15273968) and compare captions of running Javaw.exe.

Answer (score 1):

`jps` command in /jdk/bin lists all running java processes. if you want to make sure no other processes are running you can use `pkill -9 java` command.
note that it kills all running java processes.

Comment: I also want to pass some information to the running jar like the file to open. Please can you also suggest how to do that.

Comment: run your jar file like this in cmd or terminal: java -jar PlayIt.jar filePathTOpen. then in your program you can get it like this: String x = args[0];

Comment: But the jar is already running. I want it like like vlc media player. When you double click a file it gets added to the playlist